# Security wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, security, templates

As I'm learning to make wordpress templates I have a question:

I want to optimize the security of a template and Wordpress tells me to add this line:

```
defined('ABSPATH') or die("No script kiddies please!");
```

Do I have to do that for each .php file of the theme?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to add it to anything. Adding this kind of thing in a WordPress template is usually pointless. That's not to say that direct access may not be dangerous...but directly accessing a WordPress theme template or plugin usually won't do anything, as they need to run through WordPress.

To answer your question: You can add it to each theme file that you don't want to be directly accessible.